Buenas noches. Estoy recién iniciando un curso de PYTHON y al escribir en Visual Studio Code me sucede lo siguiente
Escribo hola mundo y dos más dos y no me sale nada abajo, como sale en el videotutorial que estoy viendo.

Justo abajo de la instrucción que escribiste? Es posible que te estés confundiendo con el modo interactivo o con Jupyter notebook. Comparte el tutorial para que podamos ayudarte

Justo abajo no, en la parte de abajo del todo....cuando le doy enter, debería aparecer hola mundo y 4 no...gracias.

En la terminal no me sale nada...

La terminal no hará nada mientras no se lo pidas. Debes introducir un comando ahí y presionar enter. Por ejemplo, python archivo.py para que ejecute un archivo llamado archivo.py. O puedes presionar F5 creo, se abrirá un diálogo en el que podrás elegir ejecutar o depurar tu código.

Perdón por tantas preguntas, y agradezco las respuestas, estoy viendo a Dalto, él escribe en la parte de arriba y en la terminal le da el resultado por ejemplo de 2 más dos 4 y a mi no.

Este video? https://youtu.be/nKPbfIU442g Yo cuando toco F5 me da la opción de depurar el programa así como hace él.

Tu archivo está sin guardar... Si lo acabas de crear, has escrito algo y no lo has guardado, el archivo que ejecutas está en blanco! Debes guardar tus cambios antes de ejecutar el archivo

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Cuando el interprete de comando no reconoce la instrucción es porque no le estás dando la ruta del ejecutable, o bien, no forma parte de una variable global del sistema operativo.
Desinstala lo que tengas de Python y nuevamente ejecuta el instalador y selecciona las siguientes opciones:
En la primera pantalla seleccionar:
Customize installation
En la siguiente pantalla llamada "Optional Features", seleccionar Todo.
En la siguiente pantalla llamada "Advanced Options" seleccionar:

Install Python 3.12 for all users
Associate files with Python
Create shorcuts for installed applications
Add Python to environment variables <-- ¡Esta es la Importante!!!
Precompile standard library

Y en "Customize install location": C:\Python312

Una vez que termine, cierras y vuelves a abrir el IDE y ya debe funcionar.

Creo que el problema no es que el terminal no reconozca un comando, si miras la imagen ves que está vacío.

utiliza py archivo.py en lugar de python archivo.py, al menos a mi me funcionó de esa manera, tambien asegurate de guardar el archivo cada vez que lo quieras probar y por si las dudas poner cd (la direccion donde se encuentra el archivo).
espero solucione tu problema
